# Failed geolocalization with Geopy, Nominatim: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, nonetype, geopy, nominatim

I am trying to use module Geopy, function Nominatim to geolocalize a list of addresses (contained inside a CSV file).
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim 

df = pd.read_csv('incidenti genova 3.csv', delimiter=';', error_bad_lines=False)
indirizzi = df.descrizione_strada

nom=Nominatim(user_agent="my-application") 

coordinate=[]

for element in indirizzi:
    print(element)
    target1=nom.geocode(element)[1]
    print(target1)
    coordinate.append(target1)
```

When I run it, it prints the first address of my list, then I get this error:

> ```
> TypeError                                 
> Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-9-765a06164536> in <module>()
>      13     print(element)
>      14 
> ---> 15     target1=nom.geocode(element)[1]
>      16     print(target1)
>      17     coordinate.append(target1)
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
> ```

I found out it means that it failed geolocalizing the address because the address is not complete enough.
What I want is the code to skip the elements of the list it could not geolocalize and go on printing the others.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are missing one of the very important fundamentals of coding, i.e the [`try... except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) statements

You probably wanna do something like this:

```
for element in indirizzi:
  try: 
   print(element)
   target1=nom.geocode(element)[1]
   print(target1)
   coordinate.append(target1)
  except NoneType:
   pass
```

Comment: I actually did it meanwhile. Shame on me.